# Why I am getting unsupported message while installing softwares in fedora 35

Tags: fedora, package-management

I was an ubuntu user and now switched to fedora few days back. I tried installing Spyder ide for python from software in fedora. Its not getting installed and I am getting a message stating that it snot supported. Any other options to install softwares in fedora?

Once I click on install button in software manager, its keep on showing progress, but not getting completed.

[image]

If I click on cancel, its showing message saying not supported.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is: this package has a *huge* number of dependencies, many of them large. On my Fedora Workstation 35 system, it wants to download 141 packages, weighing in at 167MB compressed, for a total of 821MB on disk.

So, it wasn't really stuck at 20% — I think that's just the common UI problem of percent-complete indicators vs. hard-to-predict totals. You can use `dnf history --reverse` from the command line to see the ID of the transaction that was attempted, and `dnf history info ###` with the corresponding number to see more of what it was trying to do.

I would try telling Software to check for updates (in order to refresh its view of the world, just in case it got confused), and then trying again, and then waiting.

You could also try `sudo dnf install python3-spyder` from the command line, to get more granular view of what's happening.

Comment: This warrants a bug report, what you're describing is simply unacceptable IMO.

Comment: Probably? "Insufficient feedback when installing a package with many megabytes of currently-uninstalled dependencies", I guess. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/issues